# DocuSign change payment total based on payment method

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

Looking to solve a use case with DocuSign payments involving changing the total payment amount based on the payment method.

Currently have a DocuSign and Stripe integration.  Our customer is looking to add payment fees as a surcharge to the total payment amount.  If recipient selects credit card, 3% is added to the total payment amount.  If recipient selects ACH, no surcharge is added to the total.

The out of the box integration between DocuSign and Stripe is not configurable or event driven.

We've looked at creating a formula in the DocuSign template and asking the recipient to select CC/ACH in the document, then adjusting the total.  Unfortunately, they can still change the payment method in the payment window, nullifying the previous calculation.

We are new to DocuSign development.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the envelope through the API, you can try to make the tab holding the value "locked":"true" thus read-only

Comment: thanks for the advisement.  The problem I'm trying to work around is changing the value in the payment modal window.  Recipient can toggle between Credit Card and ACH, if they do that, I need the total amount to change.

Alternatively, I could add the payment method selection in the document and adjust the total with a formula based on the selection but I would need to be able to dynamically adjust the payment method options in the payment modal.

Any other ideas?